# connecting to xampp from external server

Tags: php, mysql

My Error is :

> Warning: mysql_connect(): Can't connect to MySQL server on
> '0.0.0.0' (4) in /home/user/public_html/email.php
> on line 2 Can't connect to MySQL server on '0.0.0.0' (4)
>
> 0.0.0.0 = My public IP

My Goal is :

Connect to my local Xampp MySQL Database from a website I have hosted with GoDaddy. Here's the code I'm using

```
    $connect = mysql_connect("0.0.0.0:3306","DBUser", "DBpassword");
    if (!$connect) {
        die(mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db("DBname");
    $results4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE didText=0 ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
    while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($results4)) {
        $didIText = $row4['didText'];
        $postID= $row4['postID'];
        $theirNumber = $row4['phone'];
        $offer = $row4['price'];
```

Comment: `0.0.0.0` is not a valid IP. You probably mean `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` No need to define a port cause 3306 is default. Also, dont use `mysql_*` functions as they will be removed. And if you want godaddy to connect to your local database server your IP is displayed on websites such as `whatismyip.com` but that probably requires configuration changes in the php.ini to allow for that.

Comment: I realize 0.0.0.0 is not a valid IP I use my public IP which I didn't want on stack overflow. I wrote "0.0.0.0 = My Public IP" If I was to use Localhost trying to make a MySQL Query on my GoDaddy domain I'll be connecting to the GoDaddy servers. I'm trying to connect to my local machine, running xampp. @xorifelse

Comment: I assume that you have forwarded the port on your router? I assume that you have changed all your passwords from the defaults? If your IP address changes often then it may be worth registering with one of the dynamic ip dns services?

Comment: A wrong password would cause another error message. But the port forward and/or firewall settings are a likely candidate.

Comment: here you can find your info https://in.godaddy.com/help/connect-remotely-to-databases-4978

Answer (score 0):

go to windows command prompt, write ipconfig & hit enter. That will show your connection's IP. Get the IPv4 of connection that you are using, enter that in place of 0.0.0.0 . That's it.